# possible to adjust volume on my laptop up or down without having to log in?

Tags: audio, login

Is there any way to adjust the output volume of my speakers with the 
physical buttons on the keyboard without having to log in ?

If my screen is locked and  an annoying song starts to play, I need to stop it quick fast and in a hurry.  I'm not talking about doing this with soft controls via point and click. I want to do this with the actual physical (touchable) volume adjustment buttons on my machine.  But it seems like I have to go through the tedious process of logging in before I can change the volume.

Any tips most appreciated.
 -chris

Comment: What DE are you using ?

Comment: Generally this is not possible using the keyboard controls, because the screen locker is intended to lock the screen from all input.  I recall seeing wishlist bugs filed against KDE and/or GNOME asking for this, but I think it's unlikely to happen.  Perhaps someday, when we're all using Wayland, something like that could be implemented.  As an alternative, you might consider using player software like MPD or Clementine, which can be controlled over the network, even with smartphone apps.  They both work well for me.

Comment: One other possibility might be to use a gamepad.  I don't know, but I suspect that you could configure a gamepad or other game input device to control the player software, and I suspect that could work when the screen is locked.  You might need to have the gamepad software execute a script to control the player rather than sending the player keyboard input.

Comment: Hi.. thanks for confirming this is not possible, blujay. Do you want to make your comment an answer? I'll be happy to accept.  It's not the answer I want.. .but it is  cold hard reality it seems ;^)    If anyone knows the URL of the bug  for the wishlist item, please post.. I will certainly upvote it.. It seems like a really useful feature to have.  anyway.. thanx again.

Comment: @blujay - this is _very_ possible [at least in GNOME 3.6 and later](https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.6/users-lock-screen.html.en) (I'm not familiar with other DEs but I can't believe KDE doesn't also support this feature, it's usually more feature-rich than GNOME). When my screen is locked I can adjust the volume via _Fn+F11_ and _Fn+F12_ just like I do when I'm logged in (on my notebook those two keys are vol up and vol down when used with _Fn_)

Comment: @don_crissti Cool, TFTI.  I didn't remember that they had gotten that working.  Well, Chris, I guess if it's that important to you, you can try GNOME... D:

Comment: @blujay This is possible unless the screen locker arranges for it to be impossible. If it's impossible in Gnome or KDE, it's a deficiency of the screen locker, not of X. Chris, what desktop environment are you using?

Comment: hi. i'm using  gnome 2.28.2, and it's a no go on that version.  i will try upgrading and i will leave a note on how it went.    Before i do.. onne last question:  I did not see anything in System/Pref's/Screensaver dialog that seemed to have anything to do w/ controlling whether or not volume buttons were active when screen was locked.   If there is another way of configuring screen saver to do the right thing, pls let me know.    thank you guys for your help !

Comment: update: i killed gnome-screensaver and tried xscreensaver - it kicked in but when the screensaver was up my volume keys were not responsive...  maybe not screensaver?  maybe gnome itself...?   i will mos' def' do an upgrade.

Comment: @ChrisBedford - this was implemented in gnome 3.6 so no, it won't work with earlier versions.

Comment: when my new laptop comes in i will upgrade it to redhat 7.. which i hope has gnome 3.6.. if not i will install that gnome version, and will report back my results for those interested. thx 4 the help.